# Deriving $\Delta z=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y+\alpha\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, differential

I was reading a math book, which contained. 
 
"Let us consider a function $$z=f(x,y)$$ 
of two variables. If it has continuous partial derivatives, we can prove that its increment
$$\Delta z=f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)$$
corresponding to the increments $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ of its arguments, may be put in the form
$$\Delta z=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y+\alpha\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$$
And the differential will be the first 2 summands." 
Now how did they get the last expression?

Comment: That's better - I down-voted but didn't leave a comment as I was in a hurry. I needed the context you've added. Many thanks, it's helped me understand the problem. Preparing an answer now, suffice to say it's a Taylor's theorem answer...

Comment: @Bacon? Are you preparing an answer?

Comment: Is it still unclear?

Comment: What's $\alpha$?  As the question is written now, the second equation for $\Delta z$ is simply wrong.  The first order terms are correct (assuming $\partial y/\partial x$ is really $\partial f/\partial x$), but the "higher order terms" should depend on $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ I would say this is a linear approximation, i.e. like $$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2)$$ but in two dimensions.
The $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$ is a radius of point $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$, i.e. the distance from original point $(x,y)$
which plays the role of $h$ in this case. The $\alpha$ comes from the definition of $f=O(h)$ which means there is exists an $\alpha$ such that $f\le \alpha h$ and as you can see the equality in your expression should be changed by $\approx$.

Comment: This looks like a Taylor expansion.

Comment: exactly! i.e. Taylor expansion is infinite series, but when you truncate it you get a linear, quadratic, cubic etc approximation.

Comment: But then there is no need for $\approx$, equality sign is sufficient.

Comment: with $O$ notation you should use the equality, but not in your form, unless you have very special $f$

Answer (score 0):

As the question is written now, the second equation for $\Delta z$ is simply wrong.  The first order terms are correct (assuming $\partial y/\partial x$ is really $\partial f/\partial x$), but the "higher order terms" should depend on $f$.

Perhaps the equation was supposed to say:

\begin{equation}
\Delta z = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Delta y + o\left(\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}\right).
\end{equation}
(In this corrected equation we're using little-o notation.)

Comment: Yea, but proof? Also, why that little-o notation? Is there a pun intended?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal No pun intended, it really is called [little-o notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html).  I suspect that in the book you're looking at, the $\alpha$ was a typo.

Comment: No in single variable differential also, $\alpha$ was used.